# Input type is incorrect or Invalid element found in the message payload

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

We have a webservice which we are calling using Call Mediator in Developer Studio, till calling phase all went fine then we have made webservice output (Inside Body) as Mapper Input but we are getting Error: "Input type is incorrect or Invalid element found in the message payload".
My Simple Input XML as follows as i dont know why input xml mediator is unable to read this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
      <ns0:getPurchaseOrderResponse xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/prc/po/editDocument/purchaseOrderService/types/">
         <ns1:result xsi:type="ns2:PurchaseOrderResult" xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/prc/po/editDocument/purchaseOrderService/" xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/prc/po/editDocument/purchaseOrderService/types/" xmlns:tns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/svc/errors/" xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/svc/types/" xmlns:ns9="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/prc/po/viewDocument/publicFlex/purchasingDocumentHeader/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ns2:Value>
               <ns2:POHeaderId>300000001085237</ns2:POHeaderId>
            </ns2:Value>
         </ns1:result>
      </ns0:getPurchaseOrderResponse>
```

**Error Log:**

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-02-25 14:47:40,621]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.engine.input.readers.XMLInputReader} -  Element name not found : ns1:getPurchaseOrderResponse {org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.engine.input.readers.XMLInputReader}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-02-25 14:47:40,621] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.DataMapperMediator} -  DataMapper mediator : mapping failed {org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.DataMapperMediator}
Input type is incorrect or Invalid element found in the message payload : ns1:getPurchaseOrderResponse
        at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.engine.input.readers.XMLInputReader.xmlTraverse(XMLInputReader.java:170)
        at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.engine.input.readers.XMLInputReader.read(XMLInputReader.java:117)
        at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.engine.input.InputBuilder.buildInputModel(InputBuilder.java:59)
        at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.engine.core.mapper.MappingHandler.doMap(MappingHandler.java:67)
        at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.DataMapperMediator.transform(DataMapperMediator.java:306)
        at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.DataMapperMediator.mediate(DataMapperMediator.java:256)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:260)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.mediateFromContinuationStateStack(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:766)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:282)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:554)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:188)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:261)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**inputpo.xml (Input Xml for Input Data Mapper)**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
        <ns0:getPurchaseOrderResponse
            xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/prc/po/editDocument/purchaseOrderService/types/">
            <ns1:result
                xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/prc/po/editDocument/purchaseOrderService/types/"
                xmlns:tns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/svc/errors/"
                xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/svc/types/"
                xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/prc/po/editDocument/purchaseOrderService/"
                xmlns:ns9="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/prc/po/viewDocument/publicFlex/purchasingDocumentHeader/"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:PurchaseOrderResult">
                <ns2:Value>
                    <ns2:POHeaderId>300000001085237</ns2:POHeaderId>
                    <ns2:OrderNumber>ESL-PO-4</ns2:OrderNumber>
                    <ns2:OrderRevision xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ns2:DocumentTypeCode>STANDARD</ns2:DocumentTypeCode>
                    <ns2:DocumentType>Purchase Order</ns2:DocumentType>
                    <ns2:DocumentStyleId>1</ns2:DocumentStyleId>
                    <ns2:DocumentStyle>Purchase Order</ns2:DocumentStyle>
                    <ns2:ProcurementBUId>300000001071236</ns2:ProcurementBUId>
                    <ns2:ProcurementBusinessUnit>Etisalat Lanka Private Limited</ns2:ProcurementBusinessUnit>
                    <ns2:RequisitioningBUId>300000001071236</ns2:RequisitioningBUId>
                    <ns2:RequisitioningBusinessUnit>Etisalat Lanka Private Limited</ns2:RequisitioningBusinessUnit>
                    <ns2:SoldToBUId>300000001071236</ns2:SoldToBUId>
                    <ns2:SoldToBusinessUnit xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ns2:DocumentStatusCode>INCOMPLETE</ns2:DocumentStatusCode>
                    <ns2:DocumentStatus>Incomplete</ns2:DocumentStatus>
                    <ns2:BuyerId>300000001092055</ns2:BuyerId>
                    <ns2:BuyerName>PwC, Etisalat</ns2:BuyerName>
                    <ns2:BuyerEmail>etisalatpwcteam@gmail.com</ns2:BuyerEmail>
                    <ns2:CreationDate>2017-01-14T12:00:35.0Z</ns2:CreationDate>
                    <ns2:SupplierId>300000001085017</ns2:SupplierId>
                    <ns2:Supplier>PwC Pakistan</ns2:Supplier>
                    <ns2:SupplierSiteId>300000001085112</ns2:SupplierSiteId>
                    <ns2:SupplierSiteCode>PWC Pakistan</ns2:SupplierSiteCode>
                    <ns2:SupplierContactId xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ns2:SupplierContactName xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ns2:SupplierContactEmail xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ns2:SupplierCommunicationMethod>NONE</ns2:SupplierCommunicationMethod>
                    <ns2:SupplierCommunicationEmail xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ns2:SupplierCommunicationFax xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ns2:BillToLocationId>300000001071435</ns2:BillToLocationId>
                    <ns2:BillToLocationCode>Etisalat Head Office</ns2:BillToLocationCode>
                    <ns2:DefaultShipToLocationId>300000001071495</ns2:DefaultShipToLocationId>
                    <ns2:DefaultShipToLocationCode>Etisalat Main Warehouse</ns2:DefaultShipToLocationCode>
                    <ns2:CurrencyCode>PKR</ns2:CurrencyCode>
                    <ns2:Currency>Pakistan Rupee</ns2:Currency>
                    <ns2:ConversionRateTypeCode>User</ns2:ConversionRateTypeCode>
                    <ns2:ConversionRateType>User</ns2:ConversionRateType>
                    <ns2:ConversionDate xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ns2:ConversionRate>243</ns2:ConversionRate>
                    <ns2:OrderedAmount currencyCode="PKR">3144.00</ns2:OrderedAmount>
                    <ns2:TotalTaxAmount currencyCode="PKR">0</ns2:TotalTaxAmount>
                    <ns2:TotalAmount currencyCode="PKR">3144.00</ns2:TotalAmount>
                    <ns2:ProcurementCard xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ns2:DocumentDescription xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ns2:SupplierOrderNumber xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ns2:RequiredAcknowledgmentCode>N</ns2:RequiredAcknowledgmentCode>
                    <ns2:RequiredAcknowledgment>None</ns2:RequiredAcknowledgment>
                    <ns2:AcknowledgmentDueDate xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ns2:PaymentTermsId xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ns2:PaymentTerms xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ns2:CarrierId xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ns2:Carrier xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ns2:FreightTermsCode xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ns2:FreightTerms/>
                    <ns2:FOBCode xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ns2:FOB/>
                    <ns2:PayOnReceiptFlag>false</ns2:PayOnReceiptFlag>
                    <ns2:ConfirmingOrderFlag>false</ns2:ConfirmingOrderFlag>
                    <ns2:NoteToReceiver xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ns2:NoteToSupplier xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ns2:TaxationCountryCode>LK</ns2:TaxationCountryCode>
                    <ns2:TaxationCountry>Sri Lanka</ns2:TaxationCountry>
                    <ns2:DocumentFiscalClassificationCode xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ns2:DocumentFiscalClassification xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ns2:InterfaceSourceCode xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ns2:ReferenceNumber xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ns2:PurchaseOrderLine
                        xmlns:ns8="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/prc/po/viewDocument/publicFlex/purchasingDocumentLine/">
                        <ns2:LineNumber>1</ns2:LineNumber>
                        <ns2:POLineId>300000001085239</ns2:POLineId>
                        <ns2:LineTypeId>1</ns2:LineTypeId>
                        <ns2:LineType>Goods</ns2:LineType>
                        <ns2:ItemId>300000001075027</ns2:ItemId>
                        <ns2:ItemNumber>DEV123123L</ns2:ItemNumber>
                        <ns2:ItemRevision xsi:nil="true"/>
                        <ns2:ItemDescription>Nokia Handset</ns2:ItemDescription>
                        <ns2:CategoryId>300000001102045</ns2:CategoryId>
                        <ns2:CategoryName>Default Item Category</ns2:CategoryName>
                        <ns2:LineStatusCode xsi:nil="true"/>
                        <ns2:LineStatus/>
                        <ns2:SupplierItem xsi:nil="true"/>
                        <ns2:UnitOfMeasureCode>zzu</ns2:UnitOfMeasureCode>
                        <ns2:UnitOfMeasure>Unit</ns2:UnitOfMeasure>
                        <ns2:Quantity unitCode="zzu">5</ns2:Quantity>
                        <ns2:Price currencyCode="PKR">100</ns2:Price>
                        <ns2:OrderedAmount currencyCode="PKR">500</ns2:OrderedAmount>
                        <ns2:TotalTaxAmount currencyCode="PKR">0</ns2:TotalTaxAmount>
                        <ns2:TotalAmount currencyCode="PKR">500</ns2:TotalAmount>
                        <ns2:SupplierConfigurationId xsi:nil="true"/>
                        <ns2:NegotiatedFlag>false</ns2:NegotiatedFlag>
                        <ns2:UNNumberId xsi:nil="true"/>
                        <ns2:UNNumber/>
                        <ns2:UNNumberDescription/>
                        <ns2:HazardClassId xsi:nil="true"/>
                        <ns2:HazardClass/>
                        <ns2:HazardClassDescription xsi:nil="true"/>
                        <ns2:SourceAgreementId xsi:nil="true"/>
                        <ns2:SourceAgreementProcurementBUId xsi:nil="true"/>
                        <ns2:SourceAgreementProcurementBusinessUnit xsi:nil="true"/>
                        <ns2:SourceAgreementNumber xsi:nil="true"/>
                        <ns2:SourceAgreementLine xsi:nil="true"/>
                        <ns2:SourceAgreementType xsi:nil="true"/>
                        <ns2:SourceAgreementStyle xsi:nil="true"/>
                        <ns2:NoteToSupplier xsi:nil="true"/>
                        <ns2:PurchaseOrderSchedule
                            xmlns:ns7="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/prc/po/viewDocument/publicFlex/purchasingDocumentSchedule/">
                            <ns2:ScheduleNumber>1</ns2:ScheduleNumber>
                            <ns2:ScheduleStatusCode xsi:nil="true"/>
                            <ns2:ScheduleStatus/>
                            <ns2:SupplierOrderLine xsi:nil="true"/>
                            <ns2:Quantity unitCode="zzu">5</ns2:Quantity>
                            <ns2:SecondaryUOMCode xsi:nil="true"/>
                            <ns2:SecondaryUOM/>
                            <ns2:SecondaryQuantity xsi:nil="true"/>
                            <ns2:OrderedAmount currencyCode="PKR">500</ns2:OrderedAmount>
                            <ns2:TotalTaxAmount currencyCode="PKR">0</ns2:TotalTaxAmount>
                            <ns2:TotalAmount currencyCode="PKR">500</ns2:TotalAmount>
                            <ns2:CountryOfOriginCode xsi:nil="true"/>
                            <ns2:CountryOfOrigin/>
                            <ns2:ShipToLocationId>300000001071495</ns2:ShipToLocationId>
                            <ns2:ShipToLocationCode>Etisalat Main Warehouse</ns2:ShipToLocationCode>
                            <ns2:ShipToOrganizationId>300000001101675</ns2:ShipToOrganizationId>
                            <ns2:ShipToOrganizationCode>EMW</ns2:ShipToOrganizationCode>
                            <ns2:ShipToOrganizationName>ESL Main Warehouse</ns2:ShipToOrganizationName>
                            <ns2:NeedByDate xsi:nil="true"/>
                            <ns2:PromisedDate>2017-01-16</ns2:PromisedDate>
                            <ns2:OriginalPromisedDate xsi:nil="true"/>
                            <ns2:DestinationTypeCode>EXPENSE</ns2:DestinationTypeCode>
                            <ns2:DestinationType>Expense</ns2:DestinationType>
                            <ns2:EarlyReceiptToleranceDays>5</ns2:EarlyReceiptToleranceDays>
                            <ns2:LateReceiptToleranceDays>5</ns2:LateReceiptToleranceDays>
                            <ns2:LastAcceptDate>2017-01-21</ns2:LastAcceptDate>
                            <ns2:ReceiptDateExceptionActionCode>WARNING</ns2:ReceiptDateExceptionActionCode>
                            <ns2:ReceiptDateExceptionAction>Warning</ns2:ReceiptDateExceptionAction>
                            <ns2:ShipToExceptionActionCode>WARNING</ns2:ShipToExceptionActionCode>
                            <ns2:ShipToExceptionAction>Warning</ns2:ShipToExceptionAction>
                            <ns2:ReceiptCloseTolerancePercent>0</ns2:ReceiptCloseTolerancePercent>
                            <ns2:OverReceiptTolerancePercent>0</ns2:OverReceiptTolerancePercent>
                            <ns2:OverReceiptActionCode>REJECT</ns2:OverReceiptActionCode>
                            <ns2:OverReceiptAction>Reject</ns2:OverReceiptAction>
                            <ns2:ReceiptRoutingId>2</ns2:ReceiptRoutingId>
                            <ns2:ReceiptRouting>Inspection required</ns2:ReceiptRouting>
                            <ns2:AllowSubstituteReceiptsFlag>false</ns2:AllowSubstituteReceiptsFlag>
                            <ns2:MatchApprovalLevelCode>4-Way</ns2:MatchApprovalLevelCode>
                            <ns2:InvoiceMatchOptionCode>R</ns2:InvoiceMatchOptionCode>
                            <ns2:InvoiceMatchOption>Receipt</ns2:InvoiceMatchOption>
                            <ns2:InvoiceCloseTolerancePercent>0</ns2:InvoiceCloseTolerancePercent>
                            <ns2:AccrueAtReceiptFlag>true</ns2:AccrueAtReceiptFlag>
                            <ns2:TransactionBusinessCategoryCode>PURCHASE_TRANSACTION</ns2:TransactionBusinessCategoryCode>
                            <ns2:TransactionBusinessCategory>Purchase Transaction</ns2:TransactionBusinessCategory>
                            <ns2:ProductTypeCode>GOODS</ns2:ProductTypeCode>
                            <ns2:ProductType>Goods</ns2:ProductType>
                            <ns2:ProductFiscalClassificationId xsi:nil="true"/>
                            <ns2:ProductFiscalClassification xsi:nil="true"/>
                            <ns2:ProductCategoryCode xsi:nil="true"/>
                            <ns2:ProductCategory/>
                            <ns2:IntendedUseId xsi:nil="true"/>
                            <ns2:IntendedUse/>
                            <ns2:UserDefinedFiscalClassificationCode xsi:nil="true"/>
                            <ns2:UserDefinedFiscalClassification/>
                            <ns2:TaxClassificationCode xsi:nil="true"/>
                            <ns2:TaxClassification/>
                            <ns2:AssessableAmount currencyCode="PKR">500</ns2:AssessableAmount>
                            <ns2:NoteToReceiver xsi:nil="true"/>
                            <ns2:PurchaseOrderDistribution
                                xmlns:ns6="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/prc/po/viewDocument/publicFlex/purchaseOrderDistribution/">
                                <ns2:DistributionNumber>1</ns2:DistributionNumber>
                                <ns2:Quantity unitCode="zzu">5</ns2:Quantity>
                                <ns2:OrderedAmount currencyCode="PKR">500</ns2:OrderedAmount>
                                <ns2:TotalTaxAmount currencyCode="PKR">0</ns2:TotalTaxAmount>
                                <ns2:TotalAmount currencyCode="PKR">500</ns2:TotalAmount>
                                <ns2:DestinationSubinventory xsi:nil="true"/>
                                <ns2:RequesterId>300000001092055</ns2:RequesterId>
                                <ns2:RequesterName>PwC, Etisalat</ns2:RequesterName>
                                <ns2:DeliverToLocationId>300000001071495</ns2:DeliverToLocationId>
                                <ns2:DeliverToLocationCode>Etisalat Main Warehouse</ns2:DeliverToLocationCode>
                                <ns2:Requisition xsi:nil="true"/>
                                <ns2:RequisitionLine xsi:nil="true"/>
                                <ns2:DestinationChargeAccountId xsi:nil="true"/>
                                <ns2:DestinationChargeAccount xsi:nil="true"/>
                                <ns2:POChargeAccountId>300000001072215</ns2:POChargeAccountId>
                                <ns2:POChargeAccount>01-000-25111001-0000-0000-0000-0000-01-0000-0000</ns2:POChargeAccount>
                                <ns2:POAccrualAccountId>300000001072215</ns2:POAccrualAccountId>
                                <ns2:POAccrualAccount>01-000-25111001-0000-0000-0000-0000-01-0000-0000</ns2:POAccrualAccount>
                                <ns2:DestinationVarianceAccountId xsi:nil="true"/>
                                <ns2:DestinationVarianceAccount xsi:nil="true"/>
                                <ns2:POVarianceAccountId>300000001072215</ns2:POVarianceAccountId>
                                <ns2:POVarianceAccount>01-000-25111001-0000-0000-0000-0000-01-0000-0000</ns2:POVarianceAccount>
                                <ns2:ConversionDate xsi:nil="true"/>
                                <ns2:ConversionRate>243</ns2:ConversionRate>
                                <ns2:DistributionFlexfield>
                                    <ns6:PoDistributionId>300000001085241</ns6:PoDistributionId>
                                    <ns6:__FLEX_Context xsi:nil="true"/>
                                    <ns6:__FLEX_Context_DisplayValue xsi:nil="true"/>
                                    <ns6:_FLEX_NumOfSegments>0</ns6:_FLEX_NumOfSegments>
                                </ns2:DistributionFlexfield>
                            </ns2:PurchaseOrderDistribution>
                            <ns2:ScheduleFlexfield>
                                <ns7:LineLocationId>300000001085240</ns7:LineLocationId>
                                <ns7:__FLEX_Context xsi:nil="true"/>
                                <ns7:__FLEX_Context_DisplayValue xsi:nil="true"/>
                                <ns7:_FLEX_NumOfSegments>0</ns7:_FLEX_NumOfSegments>
                            </ns2:ScheduleFlexfield>
                        </ns2:PurchaseOrderSchedule>
                        <ns2:LineFlexfield>
                            <ns8:PoLineId>300000001085239</ns8:PoLineId>
                            <ns8:__FLEX_Context xsi:nil="true"/>
                            <ns8:__FLEX_Context_DisplayValue xsi:nil="true"/>
                            <ns8:_FLEX_NumOfSegments>0</ns8:_FLEX_NumOfSegments>
                        </ns2:LineFlexfield>
                    </ns2:PurchaseOrderLine>                    
                    <ns2:HeaderFlexfield>
                        <ns9:PoHeaderId>300000001085237</ns9:PoHeaderId>
                        <ns9:__FLEX_Context xsi:nil="true"/>
                        <ns9:__FLEX_Context_DisplayValue xsi:nil="true"/>
                        <ns9:_FLEX_NumOfSegments>0</ns9:_FLEX_NumOfSegments>
                    </ns2:HeaderFlexfield>
                </ns2:Value>
            </ns1:result>
        </ns0:getPurchaseOrderResponse>
```

**My Input Payload which i am giving to Proxy Service is:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:typ="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/prc/po/editDocument/purchaseOrderService/types/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <typ:getPurchaseOrder>
         <typ:poHeaderId>300000001085237</typ:poHeaderId>
      </typ:getPurchaseOrder>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Please post complete error log.

Comment: Bhathiya: Add the log in the question

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the XML file you used to generate Datamapper input schema is different from the real input xml.

Comment: this is not the case, i have added my input.xml which i am giving to data mapper and input payload for executing Proxy Service

Comment: In that case this should be analyzed properly to figure out the problem. Better to contact wso2 support.